# Counting Rows in a Access Report using letters

Tags: ms-access

I know how to count rows in an Access report using a textbox and Running sum to count rows using numbers.

I am creating a multiple choice text through a report and need to use letters for each of the answers to a question and was wondering how I could label the answer rows using lettes.

ex

```
a. Choice 1
b. Choice 2
c. Choice 3
<...>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Chr(Asc("a") + n - 1)` will convert 1 to 'a', 2 to 'b', and so on.

Say you have a "running sum" Text Box named `[answerNum]` on your report that numbers answers like this:

```
1  This is the first answer 
2  This is the second answer 
...
```

You can change the "answer numbering" from numeric (1, 2, ...) to alpha (a, b, ...) by creating another Text Box named `[answerLetter]` and setting its Control Source to

`=Chr(Asc("a") + [answerNum] - 1)`

Set `[answerNum]`'s "Visible" property to False (but don't delete it) and move the `[answerLetter]` Text Box to the desired location. Your report will now look like this:

```
a  This is the first answer
b  This is the second answer
...
```